# Python: No module named sphinx error

Tags: python, pip, python-sphinx

I have followed following [guide](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

```
$ pip install sphinx sphinx-autobuild
$ pip freeze | grep "sphinx"
sphinx-autobuild==0.6.0
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.0

$ cd docs
$ sphinx-quickstart
$ make html
```

`make html` gives following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named sphinx
make: *** [help] Error 1
```

**[Q]** How could I prevent this error from happening?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't install anything into your system's Python. Use either a virtual environment or your system's user installs to isolate packages from the system Python. The Python Packaging Authority provides an explanation of [why virtual environments are a good idea™](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#creating-virtual-environments).

I prefer to start by installing another version of Python on my system, either using the [official installers for macOS](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) (beginner) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (not beginner). Install Python 3.x unless you absolutely must use Python 2.

Next [install or upgrade your Python's packaging tools](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#requirements-for-installing-packages). This is one of the very rare times that I install or upgrade packages in my Pythons, although you may want to do so for your user.

Next [create and use a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#creating-virtual-environments).

Finally follow the [correct guide to install Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/installation.html) into your virtual environment and get started using Sphinx.

Comment: That final link is broken - is there an updated one?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I thought it might be helpful to share the solution I found.

Open the **Makefile** file, and change the following line:

`SPHINXBUILD   = python -msphinx`

To this one:

`SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -msphinx`

Comment: Where is the makefile file located (on a Mac)?

Comment: Found it myself in the Sphinx doc Project Folder