# Installed module on python cannot be detected by my project

Tags: python, linux, pyramid

I've installed PyPDF2.

```
$ sudo pip install PyPDF2
```

It was successfully installed.

```
Collecting PyPDF2
Installing collected packages: PyPDF2
Successfully installed PyPDF2-1.26.0
```

But when I run my project, it produce an error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
Server with PID 19740 exited with code 1.
Waiting for changes before reloading.
```

Of course my project runs if I comment this module but I need it.
For those who can help thanks in advance!

Just for additional info, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and I'm using Pyramid as my framework (Python).

I try to use

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

but

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf'
```

EDIT: 
output of
    pip freeze

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
Chameleon==2.24
chardet==2.3.0
cryptography==1.2.3
dnspython==1.12.0
enum34==1.1.2
FormEncode==1.3.0
html5lib==0.999
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.16
lxml==3.5.0
Mako==1.0.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Paste==1.7.5.1
PasteDeploy==1.5.2
PasteScript==1.7.5
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyinotify==0.9.6
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
PyPDF2==1.26.0
python-openid==2.2.5
repoze.lru==0.6
scgi==1.13
six==1.10.0
Tempita==0.5.2
translationstring==1.3
unity-lens-photos==1.0
venusian==1.0a8
virtualenv==15.1.0
waitress==0.8.10
WebOb==1.5.1
WebTest==2.0.18
zope.component==4.2.2
zope.deprecation==4.1.2
zope.event==4.2.0
zope.hookable==4.0.4
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Comment: Do you use `virtualenv`?

Comment: When I run my project I use $ env/bin/pserve development.ini --reload, so yes

Comment: then instead of `sudo` try to install through `pip`

Comment: If you are using `virtualenv`, You have to install `pip install PyPDF2` . If you use super user permissions it will install on the main system not in `virtualenv`.

Comment: I think you need to install pyPDF2 in your venv

Comment: See [my advice about installing packages and separate Pythons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43699835/2214933). You should *never* install packages into your system Python via `sudo pip install <I_borked_my_system_halp>`, unless you absolutely know the impact of doing so.

Comment: Do **not** post screenshots of text. Just post the text, so that it is searchable, copyable, and people that are visually impaired can also help you (their screenreaders need access to the text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install pypdf2 into your virtualenv using the pip connected to that virtualenv.

```
env/bin/pip install pypdf2
```

Anything else will install the package into the wrong environment... `sudo pip install` would place it into the system's site-packages, and `pip install` would install it into the system's site-packages but would fail because your user is not root (the only user with access to change the system's site-packages).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created `virtualenv` as root . SO my suggestion is do this way:

```
sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/
```

after that try to install `pyPDF2` again

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages after pip install PyPDF2

Comment: its still the same, when I run pserve development.ini it produce "bash: /usr/bin/pserve: No such file or directory"

Comment: tell me the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: from the command you can see you are not in your project. pip works from the system not from the virtualenv. I will suggest create a new one env without sudo and try once again.

Comment: I've managed to uninstall the PyPDF2 by sudo pip uninstall PyPDF2, and try pip freeze again, its gone now. But when I do pip install PyPDF2, same error with the above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in linux, I'm so confuse, can you tell me how can I accomplish this.

Comment: sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/ just destroy my system.

Comment: mmm. how does it effect your system . can not understand though. :/ well it will better if you go to chat room.the thread is lbig now.